# Calculating subscription churn rate in Stripe api

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I want to earn my "Churn rate" with the stripe api. I want that whenever someone does not renew their subscription, I can save a log in my database

I wanted to ask how exactly this should be done

My idea is to use stripe-webhooks, but I don't know exactly which ones and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend giving the [Using webhooks with subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks) doc from Stripe a read. It depends what you mean by "whenever someone does not renew their subscription". For tracking failure of a monthly payment, you could monitor the [invoice.payment_failed](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-invoice.payment_failed) event. For getting notified of when a subscription is cancelled, you could monitor the [customer.subscription.deleted](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-customer.subscription.deleted) event.

Comment: What do you think about events "subscription_schedule.aborted" and "subscription_schedule.canceled"?

Comment: Those are only relevant if you're using a subscription schedule: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules